# MySQL get several column associated values in one query

Tags: mysql, select, field

I have 2 tables:

```
STEP
id 
value




SCALE
id 
s1
s2
s3
s4
s5
s6
```

Now step.id is foreign key to scale.s1, scale.s2, scale.s3 etc
I want to get scale.s1-s6 value from step.
I have written this query with nested selects. Is it possible to get this values with one select?

```
SELECT (
    SELECT step.val FROM step, scale WHERE step.id = scale.s1 AND scale.id = 1) as v1,(
    SELECT step.val FROM step,scale WHERE step.id = scale.s2 AND scale.id = 1) as v2, (
    SELECT step.val FROM step,scale WHERE step.id = scale.s3 AND scale.id = 1) as v3, (
    SELECT step.val FROM step,scale WHERE step.id = scale.s4 AND scale.id = 1) as v4, (
    SELECT step.val FROM step,scale WHERE step.id = scale.s5 AND scale.id = 1) as v5, (
    SELECT step.val FROM step,scale WHERE step.id = scale.s4 AND scale.id = 1) as v6, (
    SELECT step.val FROM step,scale WHERE step.id = scale.s5 AND scale.id = 1) as v7 ;
```

Comment: Just join STEP six times.

Comment: I'd consider designing the tables differently. Step{StepId, value}, Scale{ScaleId}, ScaleStep{ScaleId, StepId} so you can just do a simple join.

Comment: Could you give me the syntax for Join Step six times please @C.Ramseyer cause I'm having trouble getting it...thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join step multiple times. Here's the first three:

```
select s.id, s1.val as v1, s2.val as v2, s3.val as v3
from scale s
join step s1 on s.s1 = s1.id
join step s2 on s.s2 = s2.id
join step s3 on s.s3 = s3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a single query with `MAX` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN scale.s1 = step.id THEN step.val END) v1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN scale.s2 = step.id THEN step.val END) v2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN scale.s3 = step.id THEN step.val END) v3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN scale.s4 = step.id THEN step.val END) v4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN scale.s5 = step.id THEN step.val END) v5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN scale.s6 = step.id THEN step.val END) v6
FROM step, scale
WHERE scale.id = 1
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa451/1).

Good luck.